# how to set the NonConvex parameters in gurobi model

Tags: gurobi

In Gurobi 9,it provides a solution way in non-convex problem which you can set the NonConvex parameter of model model to 2.However , when I try to set the parameter,the console say "No parameters matching 'NonConvex' found" , I wonder how can I use this parameter? thanks for giving me some help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved.My gurobi license is 8.0 version,although the gurobi has updated to 9.0 version. It needs to update license to 9.0 version